# Can't access filename with $_FILES method, PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to build a file uploader, with a youtube tutorial that doesn't cover files, and right now I am stuck on the name. Using $_Files returns nothing and I am unsure as to why. :/

I tried to echo it out, but nothing comes back.

Everything else seems to work though.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$con){
die("Can not connect: " . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("example",$con);

if(isset($_POST['update'])){
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE repo SET location='$_POST[location]', name='$_POST[name]', description='$_POST[description]' WHERE location='$_POST[hidden]'";               
mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $con);
};

if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
$DeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM repo WHERE location='$_POST[hidden]'";          
mysql_query($DeleteQuery, $con);
};

if(isset($_POST['add'])){

$AddQuery = "INSERT INTO repo (name, id, image, location, partners, description, date) VALUES ('$image_name', '','$_POST[uimage]', '$_POST[ulocation]', '$_POST[upartners]', '$_POST[udescription]', NOW())";         
mysql_query($AddQuery, $con);
};



$sql = "SELECT * FROM repo";
$myData = mysql_query($sql,$con);
echo "<table border=1>
<tr>
<th>Image</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Location</th>
<th>Partners</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Date</th>
</tr>";
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
    ?>
<form action="mydata5.php"
method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<?php
echo "<tr>";

echo "<td>" . "<img src=Assets/Images/" . $record['name'] . " </td>";

echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=topic value=" . $record['name'] . " </td>";

echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=name value=" . $record['location'] . " </td>";

echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=name value=" . $record['partners'] . " </td>";

echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=description value=" . $record['description'] . " </td>";

echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=description value=" . $record['date'] . " </td>";

echo "<td>" . "<input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $record['location'] . " </td>";

echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=update value=update" . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=delete value=delete" . " </td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</form>";
}
echo "<form action=mydata5.php method=post>";
echo "<tr>";

// echo "<td><input type=file name=uimage></td>";

?>

<td><input type="file" name="uimage" id="uimage"></td>

<?php
$file = $_FILES['uimage']['tmp_name'];
$image_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['uimage']['name']);
echo $_FILES['uimage']['error'];

echo "<td><input type=hidden name=uname></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=ulocation></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=upartners></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=udescription></td>";

echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=add value=add" . " </td>";
echo "</form>";
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add this in form tag, enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the form tag.

Answer (score 2):

For file type fields you need to add `enctype` attribute in your form so that uploaded files can be access using $_FILES

Update form starting tag with below

```
<form action="mydata5.php"
method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick help. I added it and edited my post. I still doesn't seem to do anything. Am I using my name/id wrong?

Comment: Yes, you need to pack the field name in quotes

Comment: when I do that the site doesn't load at all anymore. :/

Comment: update your form to pack field type and name in quotes and then check $_FILES['uimage']['error'] or check whether any error occurred or not

Comment: I put in the error check in the beginning and it tells me uimage is and undefined index. sigh
I changed the forms too, to no avail it seems :C

Comment: in your code there are two separate forms. 
And you have added enctype attribute in the form which does not contains file type field. Please add this form attribute in the form which contains file type field

Answer (score 0):

Check your Insert Query.You are using **$_POST** for image name. That is wrong.

Comment: what? 0_0 no I am not.

$AddQuery = "INSERT INTO repo (name, id, image, location, partners, description, date) VALUES ('$image_name', '','$_POST[uimage]', '$_POST[ulocation]', '$_POST[upartners]', '$_POST[udescription]', NOW())";         
mysql_query($AddQuery, $con);